# How to flip a Camera image upside down?

Tags: ros, camera, image-view, stere-image-proc, vrep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I'm using V-REP to generate a simulated environment for a robot to function in, and have two vision sensors being used as stereo cameras to be sent to ROS. Annoyingly, when I send the data from V-REP to ROS, the image appears flipped (upside-down).

[image: VREP+ROS]

Since I have to use stereo_image_proc anyway, is it possible to form the CameraInfo such that the normalised image will be flipped back in the correct direction? Or any other possible way to flip the camera on the ROS side of things?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242894/how-to-flip-a-camera-image-upside-down?/) by [adammw](https://answers.ros.org/users/27881/adammw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-09-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Within ROS you could define the TF frames for your cameras as being inverted.

Note that image processing expects an frame ID with the `_optical` suffix, which [uses a different orientation convention](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html#suffix-frames) than normal ROS frames of reference.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0